# Stuck in postMessage and MessageChannel

Tags: javascript, postmessage, message-channel

I'm confused with `postMessage` and `MessageChannel`.

Here are some codes from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageChannel):

```
var channel = new MessageChannel();
var para = document.querySelector('p');

var ifr = document.querySelector('iframe');
var otherWindow = ifr.contentWindow;

ifr.addEventListener("load", iframeLoaded, false);

function iframeLoaded() {
  otherWindow.postMessage('Hello from the main page!', '*', [channel.port2]);
}

channel.port1.onmessage = handleMessage;
function handleMessage(e) {
  para.innerHTML = e.data;
}
```

I thought `postMessage` method can only take **two** arguments, the codes above showing that it can take **three**, but there is nothing about the **third** argument of `postMessage` method.

So there are my questions:

1. **What's the meaning of the third argument of `postMessage` method?**
2. I know the usage of `MessageChannel`, but it seems to be useless, **Why/When should we use MessageChannel?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MessageChannel` is basically a 2-way communication pipe. Think of it as an alternative to window.postMessage / window.onmessage - but a somewhat easier and more configurable.

[This guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API/Using_channel_messaging) explains the meaning of postMessage's 3rd parameter:

> **An object, the ownership of which is transferred to the receiving browsing context.** In this case, we are transferring MessageChannel.port2 to the IFrame, so it can be used to receive the message from the main page.

P.S. I find [this guide from Opera](https://dev.opera.com/articles/window-postmessage-messagechannel/#channel) a bit easier to read than Mozilla's.

Comment: Solved all my confusion, Thanks for sharing!